# Azure Data Factory Decompress

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-data-factory

I have a question. I have some .zip files on my FTP location, and i want to decompress and copy them to ADLS. In documentation there is clear explanation for this:

"Read .zip file from FTP server, decompress it to get the files inside, and land those files into Azure Data Lake Store. You define an input FTP dataset with the compression type JSON property as ZipDeflate."

I tried with this and on my ADLS i get compress file. I tried to put file properties, to define delimiter and stuff, and still getting compressed file on data lake store. 
I think its how i define output dataset. Is there some rules how to define output dataset if input dataset are .zip files from FTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely defined your output dataset's compression as ZipDeflate also, thats why you are getting the zipped file on ADLS. Try changing your output dataset (the same where you configure the path in ADLS) so it doesn't use compression. You should have in your copy activity the input dataset where you configure the ftp, with compression and the output dataset, where you configure most stuff for the lake, without compression.

This way you are telling data factory to get a zipped file, and save it unzipped on ADLS.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your answer. 
I defined copy behaviour on my output dataset as a binary copy. 
My logic: source sink will take files and decompress them, and I want a binary copy to my output. 
I now see, that in my .zip folder at data lake store inside is decompressed text file. 
So it just saved that folder hierarchy i guess.

Comment: Source is from where you get the data, sink is where you store it. Source is tied with input dataset, sink is tied with output dataset. All your output should not have any compression configured so it saves the unzipped file.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. 
For zip file size 90mb it took 2,5 hour to copy and decompress it. (decompressed size 270mb) 
Is it ok to take that long or? I know it depends on server and stuff, just want your opinion.

Comment: It depends on the hardware of your integration runtime's pc (if the ftp server is on premise and you use an IR), and also depends on the bandwidth of the ftp server. The unzipping process shouldn't take that long.

Comment: Just checked, my throughput is 9kbs. 
I will try with a binary copy and then unzip with u sql custom extractor.

Comment: Hey Martin, just wanted  to check whether we can perform .7z decompression with the same approach?

Comment: Hey there, last time i tried it wasnt possible. 7z is generally a low compatibility mode of compression. If you are using 7-zip to compress files, you can use it to compress in one of the supported formats, like GZip, BZip2 or Zip. Hope this helped!

Comment: is zipping / unzipping one of the integration runtime features that requires a Java Runtime Environment? certain things like Parquet format writing require that, whereas other things such as CSV reading and writing do not